# Getting error during Dependency Injection , Guice.createInjector

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice

Getting error during Dependency Injection , Guice.createInjector ... java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive load of: .()

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure that all class are Singleton

ClassA -> ClassB
ClassC -> ClassA

Error message will be for Recursive load of: ClassB

ClassA might not be Singleton.This has fixed my issue.Posting it for others